# Calculations of different columns and recording the calculated output in one row below in Mysql Query

Tags: mysql

I have a Table:-

```
 ----------------+--------------+--------------+--------------------+
 | IsFirstChunk | BufferedTime       | ElapsedTime | TotalBufferTime|
 +----+--------------+----------------+--------------+--------------+
 | Yes          | 9.056693603959156  | 13.434      | NULL            |
 | NULL         | 8.397168452045355  | 13.915      | NULL            |
 | NULL         | 9.480674058760885  | 14.576      | NULL            |
 | NULL         | 8.25989921902355   | 15.816      | NULL            |
 | NULL         | 9.029792805273495  | 18.573      | NULL            |
 | NULL         | 9.55641146650022   | 26.385      | NULL            |
 | NULL         | 7.567281197192748  | 37.274      | NULL            |
 | NULL         | 9.046965152922192  | 46.142      | NULL            |
 | NULL         | 8.135399698570493  | 56.825      | NULL            |
```

i want to calculate the columns BufferTime and ElapsedTime and insert that output to TotalBufferTime column but i want to record the output in one row below of the TotalBufferTime column not in the adjacent row.

I want to do something like this :-

```
update RequestInfo SET `TotalBufferTime` = BufferedTime + ElapsedTime;
```

only thing is i want record the output  one row below of the TotalBufferTime

```
+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------------+
| IsFirstChunk | BufferedTime       | ElapsedTime | TotalBufferTime|
+----+--------------+----------------+--------------+--------------+
| Yes          | 9.056693603959156  | 13.434      | 0              |
| NULL         | 8.397168452045355  | 13.915      | 22.4906936     |
| NULL         | 9.480674058760885  | 14.576      | 22.31216845    |
```

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query. Consider ignoring columns not relevant to the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
update RequestInfo join (
    select curr.id, (
        select (prior.BufferedTime + prior.ElapsedTime) AS value  
          from RequestInfo prior
         where prior.id < curr.id
      order by prior.id desc
       limit 1) value
      from RequestInfo curr
  ) g on g.id = RequestInfo.id
set RequestInfo.TotalBufferTime = g.value;
```

Comment: Getting Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '$getAllFromTable = getAllFromTable()' at line 1

Comment: @sonadas, Check it now.